# RC Op-Amp Circuit Analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am trying to calculate the gain Vout/Vin of the circuit below. I'm not really sure where to start, can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc)(49m:31s) video by Dave Jones where he explains what an op-amp is and how it works. It helped me when none of my teachers could get down on my level.

Comment: The currents into the + and - op amp terminals are both zero, hence the R1/C1/R2 series circuit is a voltage divider across Vout and ground (0V). The other relationship you need relates the op amp input voltages: V- = V+ ; then you can derive and equation for Vout/Vin

Comment: Start by labelling Vin and Vout.

Comment: Given finite common-mode rejection, is this not a potential oscillator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that:

- no current flows into the input of the opamp
- the input voltages of the opamp are the same

Then write down and solve the Kirchoff equations.

Comment: Will the input voltage of the op amp be Vin or will the point between C1 and R2 be Vin?

Comment: The + and - signs in the opamp symbol denotes its inputs.